# How to describe a single item within supplies?

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to translate terms used in a database to terms used by end-users. There is a supplies table which holds information on supplies held in stock. Supplies is generic on purpose, as there is no one specific category or type. Each record details a single item/thing held and what it is, how much is in stock, etc.

I refer to supplies as 'supplies' for the end-user, but I'm struggling with the singular form.

- I've tried 'supply' but it doesn't seem to fit, e.g. "add a supply" and "edit a supply" doesn't sound right.
- The word 'item' doesn't mean much without context and using that in actions also feels awkward, e.g. "add an item" – an item of what, add to where?

Should I stick with 'supply', or is there a better term?

Comment: I suspect you're going to end up with qualifying "item": supply item, stock item, inventory item, etc. Of course, there is the term ***good*** (as in *goods*), but that's likely to be even less well-received. Someone may know of a better term.

Comment: "Add a supply" is wrong, as you suspect. A supply is a source of supplies, not an item in the supply. For instance, "Their supply of [ammunition | food | beer] was dwindling alarmingly."

Comment: An item is clearly the right word. Everybody who speaks English knows it. You say "add an item" – an item of what, add to where?", Well surely that is precisely what the documentation is supposed to *tell* the user. If it doesn't then it is not good documentation.

Comment: Sometimes "New **entry**" is used.

Comment: Singular [good](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good) is another possibility, used in fields like economics, but is likely to confuse the general user. Problem is you seem to want terms familiar to end-users rather than people experienced with stock control, and the layperson will probably say "thing" or "item" or even "thingumajig".

Answer (score 1):

*Inventory item* or *inventory entry* should serve you well. I am partial to the former.

Answer (score 1):

If each record has a quantity in stock, your record granularity appears to be at the level of [Stock Keeping Unit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_keeping_unit)  or SKU, a very common jargon term in the warehouse and retail domains.

The action would be "Add a SKU"